# Prefixing www to my Heroku app doesn't work

Tags: heroku

My React app works only when I don't add www. to the front of my website. I am not using a custom domain. I'm not sure what I'm supposed to see but when I run `heroku domains` in my CLI it returns:

```
=== ninnycode-f Heroku Domain
ninnycode-f.herokuapp.com
```

Should I expect to see www. in there? Does anyone know what's going on?

This works:
http://ninnycode-f.herokuapp.com

This doesn't work:
http://www.ninnycode-f.herokuapp.com/

Works but doesn't default to 'secure':
ninnycode-f.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

Heroku creates a host using you application name ie `{app_name}.herokuapp.com', this works with both HTTP and HTTPS.

I don't think you can change the hostname, even adding 'www' in front unless you add a [custom domain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)